# 4 row 4 columns bootstrap responsive carousel animation script

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need this type of 4 row 4 columns bootstrap responsive carousel animation script

```
     <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->
```

first slide is workingin 4 row and 4 column but second slide is displayed only one row and 4columns only, how to display the 4 row and 4 columns in carousel

Comment: please add your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: @PratikDeshmukh The OP shared his code, explain well the context....

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple `item.active` in your carrousel, it's not good.

*If you want 4 rows and 4 columns in each slide, so you have to set 4 rows with 4 columns in each slide too.*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/9o6kcnGsWp

**HTML**:

```
     <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item-->

            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.item--></div>


        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->

        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.item-->
```